# In Django, how do I set the default so that every model is created with INNODB?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

Right now, Django defaults to MYISAM...but I want to change it so that everytime I create a new table it is innodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that in settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'
DATABASE_OPTIONS = {"init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB"}
```

**UPDATE**

For Django >= 1.2 this should be write like this:

```
DATABASES = {
             'default': {
                         'ENGINE': 'mysql',
                         'OPTIONS': {'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB'}
                        }
            }
```